# Using "allow-unrelated-histories" and merging

Tags: git, github

I've been trying to learn github for awhile now and I always consistently run into the same problem.  
Here is my sequence:
In short, I create a local repository.  I then set the remote according to the URL from my remote repository on github.com.  *I initialized this  remote repository with a readme file.*  I then try to pull from my remote so I can push everything from local onto my remote. I constantly get an error "refusing to merge unrelated histories", unless I use the command --allow-unrelated-histories.

I understand that git is trying to merge the two and it can't find a relation between the repositories (due to the readme file), but how do I create this relation without "allowing unrelated histories"?  I feel like I will somehow end up merging the incorrect things if I am always using unrelated histories.

Shouldn't me sending a pull request from the remote to local, "pull" my readme file, add it to my local repository/branch I am working in and sync?

Should I create a local repository, and not put anything in remote until first push (i.e. no readme) from local?  Otherwise, I should only clone the remote repository?  Is this a best practice?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is:

- create a local repository without cloning
- create a remote repository in github
- set the remote repository in the local one
- trying to pull/merge

The two repos are different and cannot be merged.

What you can do:

- after set the remote in the local repository, you can perform a forced push: `git push --force`. Pay attention you will lose everything on the remote side, but is acceptable if you will lose just the default README.
- create the github repo by not checking the `Initialize` option, so the remote repository is empty and you will not have histories issue.
- create the github repo as first action, than clone to the local repository. You'll get a local repository with the README file already committed and the remote reference already set.

Comment: Thanks Yusef.  This is very clear and provides me with a blueprint for not causing myself headaches.

Answer (score 3):

If you have already got a local repository which contains commits the best way would be to create an empty GitHub Repository (**do not** check Initialize this repository with a README). Then it should be possible to set up the remote and push without any issues since the remote repository does not have a history yet.

On the other hand if you do not have local commits yet and would like to start a new repository simply create your GitHub Repository with a README and then clone the repository.